# Changing url using contenteditable and jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, contenteditable

Having problems replacing a part of a querystring taken from an MVC actionlink with changes in the contentediable text. Can get the first button to display the correct output but not the rest. Any ideas?

```
<br />
<div class="largeImageSection">
    <div class="galleryImageNameContainer">
        <span class="editableText" data-filenameexclext="Change me 1!" >Change me 1!</span>
    </div>
    <div class="galleryButtonContainer">
        <span class="renameButton" >
            <a href="http://www.google.com/RenameUploadedFile?fileNameExclExtension=checkthis&fileExtension=.jpg&directory=banners&newFileNameExclExtension=placeHolder"></a>
            <button onclick="$(this).siblings().first().click();" >Rename</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="largeImageSection">
    <div class="galleryImageNameContainer">
        <span class="editableText" data-filenameexclext="Change me 2!" >Change me 2!</span>
    </div>
    <div class="galleryButtonContainer">
        <span class="renameButton" >
            <a href="http://www.google.com/RenameUploadedFile?fileNameExclExtension=checkthis&fileExtension=.jpg&directory=banners&newFileNameExclExtension=placeHolder"></a>
            <button onclick="$(this).siblings().first().click();" >Rename</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="largeImageSection">
    <div class="galleryImageNameContainer">
        <span class="editableText" data-filenameexclext="Change me 3!" >Change me 3!</span>
    </div>
    <div class="galleryButtonContainer">
        <span class="renameButton" >
            <a href="http://www.google.com/RenameUploadedFile?fileNameExclExtension=checkthis&fileExtension=.jpg&directory=banners&newFileNameExclExtension=placeHolder"></a>
            <button onclick="$(this).siblings().first().click();" >Rename</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".editableText").attr("contenteditable", "true");
    var theContent = $(".editableText"); // set the content.

    $(".renameButton a").click(function (e) {
        var originalContent = $(".editableText").data("filenameexclext");
        var testContent = "newFileNameExclExtension=placeHolder";
        var editedContent = "newFileNameExclExtension=" + theContent.html();
        $(this).attr("href", $(this).attr("href").replace(testContent, editedContent));
        alert(editedContent);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need

```
var theContent = $(".editableText").text();
```

to get the text inside the element?